# Storing a single space character in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, pdo

I've written a PHP script to populate a MySQL table with Unicode data. I've run into a few minor problems, though. For example, the `character` column for the *space* character (id = 32) is empty, even when I run the following command separately:

```
UPDATE unicode SET `character` = ' ' WHERE id = 32;
```

Any ideas? Here's the script that I'm using to populate the table (the included script `common.php` defines the `database` function, which is a PDO object):

```
<?php

include_once('common.php');

// Fetch data from Unicode website
$file = fopen('http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt', 'r');

// Iterate through each line of the file
while($row = fgets($file)) {

    // Gather data
    $column = explode(';', $row);
    $id = hexdec($column[0]);
    $name = $column[1];
    $general_category = $column[2];
    $uppercase_mapping = hexdec($column[12]);
    $lowercase_mapping = hexdec($column[13]);
    $titlecase_mapping = hexdec($column[14]);

    // Build the database query
    $query = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE INTO unicode VALUES (%d, CHAR(%d USING UTF8), '%s', '%s', %d, %d, %d)",
        $id,
        $id,
        $name,
        $general_category,
        $uppercase_mapping,
        $lowercase_mapping,
        $titlecase_mapping);

    database()->query($query);
    echo $id.' ';
}

?>
```

Comment: Since you're using PDO, why are you using `sprintf` to compose your queries? This is not a safe alternative to using [proper SQL placeholders](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: How are you determining that it's empty?

Comment: @AlainCollins: By inspection. I'm using MySQL workbench to probe values.

Comment: @AlainCollins: I also used the method suggested by taxman: `SELECT HEX(\`character\`) FROM unicode WHERE id=32`. This result was empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `CHAR` column type your database driver may be stripping off trailing spaces automatically. Some drivers may be doing this even on `VARCHAR` data if they are not configured to preserve them.

You can check what's actually in the database by selecting out a hex-encoded version:

```
SELECT HEX(character) FROM unicode WHERE id=32
```

You should be seeing `20`, the hexadecimal equivalent of 32.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I just tried `SELECT HEX(\`character\`) FROM unicode WHERE id=32` and the result was empty. The same query with `id=33` returns `21`. Still not sure how to remedy this...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because `CHAR` is space padded, fixed-size, and space is a special character.

Comment: This may be [a long-standing bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8546) in MySQL.

Comment: Ah, I see. Should I use a different type then?

Comment: You might be able to work around this by adding a dummy character at the end that you ignore in your application.

Answer (score 0):

`character` must be of type `CHAR`

Comment: @Clodaldo: I just double-checked; `character` is indeed of type `CHAR`.